# How to rectify SSH error: Heroku, in my Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, ssh

I'm new to SSH. I'm working my way through the Heroku tutorial "Set up SSH for Git":

Return to the terminal mac and verify your configuration by entering the following command

```
git push heroku master
```

**I get the error:**

```
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.132)' can't be established. 
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
No matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: maybe try HTTP Git instead of SSH Git - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-git - it's much easier to setup.

Comment: Have you added your ssh public keys on Heroku? If yes, try removing the content of your `.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Comment: sorry for late, add added my key to heroku, but not working heroku keys:add

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Marysmith/d8ab51e27f70d7412e8a i updated